Can I ask questions regarding fictional family trees?
I have a couple of questions regarding the genealogy and family history of witches and wizards within the Harry Potter universe.
Would such questions be valid on this Stack Exchange site?
Or does it have to be genealogy and family history of actual people?

Questions regarding family trees in fiction occasionally crop up on Literature.SE.
Alternatively you could try Movies & TV or SciFi & Fantasy.
You would be much better served posting your questions there rather than here, but check their requirements first.

Although https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic does not explicitly include or exclude such questions from the scope of this site, I think that genealogy and family history of fictitious characters from books, movies, etc should be explicitly off-topic for G&FH SE.

Let's unpack this.
Situation 1:
Let's say you have attended a presentation or webinar and the presenter has used characters from Harry Potter as an example. You have a follow-up question, and the presenter is not available, so you want to ask here.
Since there won't be an actual historical record you can cite, your recourse would be to cite the presentation itself. I would argue that this should be disallowed because reproducing the presenter's slide or handout without their permission is a violation of copyright.
Situation 2:
You think the author has made a mistake in a family tree or in a relationship or some other family history related matter in the story.  You want someone to look over the relevant piece of the story and vet the author's work.
I would argue that this should be disallowed under our existing rule against celebrity genealogy.  Harry Potter or any wizards in the story are not your family nor are they your clients. How likely is it that your question would also be of use to a genealogist who is studying the family history of actual historical people?
Conclusion:
I would check other sites on the network to see what their on-topic and dont-ask help says.
For example: if an author is making up a family tree for a story of their own, they might see if Worldbuilding allows discussion of genealogy. I think that family history would fall under the languages and culture rubric in their on-topic article, but I'm not a mod or member of that site, so I would defer to the mods there.
In my opinion, discussions of this kind are more appropriate in chat. They don't belong on the main site for GenealogySE.
